# How to make a posts page display only intros of posts?

Tags: posts

My blog, the Posts page here: http://richardclunan.com/blog - displays full blog posts. I'd like it to display only the intros to the posts, and users click into a post to read the full post -- because users will then be able to more easily scroll through the posts to decide which ones to read.

How do I make the page richardclunan.com/blog display only post intros?

.........
Edit:

I found a 'category.php' file in my 'twentyeleven' folder. But not in 'twentyeleven-child'. So I guess it's the one in 'twentyeleven'.

I couldn't find:

```
the_content();
```

But I found the following 7 lines of code in different places -- each has the the word 'content' in -- is it any of these lines I need to change?:

```
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<div class="entry-content">

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

</div><!-- #content -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go inside the code of your category.php and...

**Change:**

```
the_content(); //or similer
```

**to:**

```
the_excerpt();
```

Goog luck..

**Revised Answer for twenty eleven theme:**

**1. Open content.php and search for this line:**

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
```

**2. change it to this:**

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_category() || is_archive() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
```

Hope this helps..
Best regards, Sagive.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not sure where to find category.php -- can I access it through my Wordpress Dashboard? Or do I need to do it through my hosting? I found a file called 'category.php' in 'wp-includes' in my hosting, though I couldn't find the word 'content' in that file; and if possible I'd prefer to edit text through Wordpress Dashboard.

Comment: It will be in /wp-content/themes/{your theme folder}/

Comment: I think i found the file, but I couldn't find the line of code -- I've edited my question with details...

Comment: Haven't used get_template_part as of yet, but can you try replacing 'get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );' with 'the_excerpt();'

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: Ohh.. your using twenty eleven.. see my revised answer :)

Comment: How about it? got it to work?